# Translation of "I would be more than happy to (do something)."

Tags: traducción, selección-de-palabras

What would be some natural ways to express being *"more than happy"* to do something in Spanish?

For example:

> - I am more than happy to help you with your homework whenever you need it.
> - I would be more than happy to help you move on Saturday.
> - I'd be more than happy to translate that document for you next week.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A direct translation of 'i am more than happy' would be

> 'estoy más que feliz'

I also suggest using

> 'estoy encantado/a'
>
> 'estaría encantado' (the conditional makes it sound more natural)
>
> 'me encantaría'
>
> 'me gustaría mucho'
>
> 'estaría muy feliz"
>
> 'estaría más que feliz'
>
> 'me agradaría mucho'

For example

> 'Estoy más que feliz de ayudarte con tu tarea cuando lo necesites.'
>
> 'Estaría encantado de ayudarte con la mudanza el sábado'
>
> 'Me gustaría mucho traducir ese documento para vos la semana que viene.

Comment: 'me encantaría' or 'estaría encantado' are OK. The rest, I'd never use them in that context.

Comment: @MauricioScheffer I also prefer saying 'me encantaría' but I wanted to offer other options.

Answer (score 3):

> Me encantaría

```
I would love to
```

> Sería un placer

```
It would be a pleasure
```

> Estaría más que contento de...

```
I would be more than happy to...
```

The first and second are the most natural. The third is the most literal, but doesn't sound as good in Spanish as it does in English.